# SQL - get the first X words of a string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to 'cut' customer reviews (strings) to the first 50 words, in Biq Query SQL.
In the end to display in data studio only these 50 first words in a table.
Help someone ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to find the position of the 50th space symbol and do substring:

```
select if(instr(mycolumn, ' ', 1, 50) > 0, substr(mycolumn, 1, instr(mycolumn, ' ', 1, 50) - 1), mycolumn) 
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT left(colname,50);

for eg.

SELECT 
    left("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.",50);
```

Output - [image]

Comment: this takes the first 50 characters, not words